# PHP - Export CSV - First Case not recognize

Tags: php, wordpress, csv

I am trying to do an export plugin for wordpress. This plugin export in csv a custom type and with another plugin (not create by me) I can import the csv.

Problem come from my plugin, when I want to import a file I have exported, the first case is not recognized.

I need to change the encoding the file (with notepad++) to UTF8 w/o BOM and the first case works.

All the unnecessary code is removed.

```
    $data = array();
$attribut = array();

$ligne_csv = array(); 
$attribut[]="post_title";
$attribut[]="post_content";
$attribut[]="post_status";

$data[0] = $attribut;
$ligne_csv[]="bob";
$ligne_csv[]="richard";
$ligne_csv[]="publish";
$data[1]=$ligne_csv;

    header('Content-Type: application/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.csv');

$outstream = fopen("php://output", 'w');
fputcsv($outstream, $data[0], ';');
fputcsv($outstream, $data[1], ';');

fclose($outstream);
```

In the importer, trying to compare like this

`if (in_array($data_row[$c],array_keys($post_type->default_options)))`

and "post_title" is not in the "array_keys" when he is in the first case.

Thank you.

Edit : If I use a little hack and put the first column empty ($attribut[]="";), everything is ok but maybe there is another method

Answer (score 0):

this helps me.try this headers
header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
header('Content-type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

Comment: Thank you for response. Already try, not import the first case. Look like the first case is not the same encoding than other